# php get the number from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this string

> @[123:peterwateber] hello there 095032sdfsdf! @[589:zzzz]

I want to get **123 and 589** how do you that using regular expression or something in PHP?

Note: peterwateber and zzzz are just examples. any random string should be considered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget the lookahead so you don't match `095032`:

```
$foo = '@[123:peterwateber] hello there 095032sdfsdf! @[589:zzzz]';
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+(?=:)/", $foo, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]); // array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "123" [1]=> string(3) "589" }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will extract one or more numeric characters in a row:

```
preg_match_all('#\d+#', $subject, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called preg_match_all

The first parameter accepts a regular expression - The following example shows 'match at least one digit, followed by any number of digits. This will match numbers.

The second param is the string itself, the subject from which you want extraction

The third is an array into which all the matched elements will sit. So first element will be 123, second will be 589 and so on

```
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: hey.. I forgot to mention In my post my priority in getting the number in the string is matched when "@[123:some text here]" is found

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get that. Could you be a little more clear? Do you want the numbers to be printed?

Comment: "@[123:peterwateber]" preg_match_all should be based.

if the string is "hello nikhil @[123:peterwateber] its 6th of may" the output should be "123" when preg_match_all. Therefore, 123 should be get in the string that has the following value "@[number:string]"

Comment: Oh, then use this - preg_match_all("/@\[[0-9]+:[A-Za-z]+\]/", $string, $matches);

It says - get an '@', followed by open square brackets, one or more digits followed by a colon, followed by one or more characters (upper and lower case) followed by close of square bracket

Then do the previous preg match on result of this.